# How to fill blank data using several data frames

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two data frames as follows:

```html
df1<- read.table( text="id time group class  income
  12 NA NA NA NA
  17 NA NA NA NA
                   19 NA NA NA NA
                   36 NA NA NA NA
                  14 NA NA NA NA
                  15 NA NA NA NA
                   8 NA NA NA NA
                   22 NA NA NA NA
                   33 NA NA NA NA
                    11 NA NA NA NA
                  ",h=T)
```

The second data frame is as follows:

```html
df2<- read.table( text="id time group class  income age
17 3 A 1 2 12
11 6 A 3 12 11
36 9 E 2 11 23
19 19 E 2 13 13
8 23 M 2 14 14
15 11 M 1 16 13
12 3 P 1 15 15
14 3 Q 2 13 13
33 4 Z 3 19 13
22 5 G 3 20 11",h=T)
```

I want to get the following table using ids

```html
df3<- read.table( text="id time group class  income

12 23 P 1 15
17 3 A 1 2
19 3 E 2 13
36 5 E 2 11
14 3 Q 2 13
15 3 M 1 16
8 23 M 2 14
22 5 G 3 20
33 4 Z 3 19
11 6 A 3 12",h=T)
```

I am sorry, but I was unsuccessful to find some possible solutions to show my attempt. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think the values in expected are not matching

Comment: Family join the package `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution assuming you want the order of `id` from `df1` with most of the data from `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  select(id) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  select(-age)

Joining, by = "id"
   id time group class income
1  12    3     P     1     15
2  17    3     A     1      2
3  19   19     E     2     13
4  36    9     E     2     11
5  14    3     Q     2     13
6  15   11     M     1     16
7   8   23     M     2     14
8  22    5     G     3     20
9  33    4     Z     3     19
10 11    6     A     3     12
```